# Implementing Drag Drop in Web application that works on iDevices and all other desktop browsers also

Tags: jquery, ipad, html, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

I have a webapp that will also be run on the browsers of iDevices. The webpage consists of 4 portlets. I need to implement a functionality where the portlets can be dragged and dropped.What are the events that i need to capture since they should work on all the iDevices.  Should i be implementing this by jquery or with HTML5 elements. I came accross some plugins like redplugin which helps me do a swap animation but it fails to work on iPads Safari browser. Here is what i mean, http://interface.eyecon.ro/demos/sort_floats.html

Comment: am able to do the handling of touch events on iDevices with jQuery UI Touch Punch. now looking forward to something that when i drag and then release the portlet should also be able to place by itself.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using jQuery UI you can try **jQuery UI Touch Punch** (http://touchpunch.furf.com/)

It works like a charm for the most "classic" use of jQuery UI, including all drags.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look in this plugin/hack for `jQuery UI`:

[jQuery.touchPunch](http://touchpunch.furf.com/)

He add the touch support to `jQuery UI` mouse events like `Drag&Drop`.